# Rearrange ConEmu tabs like in MTPuTTY

Tags: conemu

I know that I can open a new shell in a split fashion via `Ctrl Shift E` and `Ctrl Shift O` but I can't seem to figure out how to take multiple already running tabs and rearrange them into a single split view like can be done in [MTPuTTY](http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/). Is this something that can be done and, if so, how do I do it? Here is an example of a layout I'd like to do with various already running tabs:
[image]